# javascript function to throw null on all occasions if value is not present

Tags: javascript

I'm developing web application, in this I received error like `Undefined,null,empty,etc` if the value is not present.

I need only `null` if value is not present.

Comment: We need _a lot_ more context as to what the issue is, the code producing the error, and what you've tried to resolve it.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Please provide the function and more context.

Comment: This is entirely too broad of a question. "I received error like Undefined,null,empty,etc if the value is not present" where? In a function, in an IF statement, on some random line of code? And where is the "value" coming from, because depending on that your options are numerous on how to default it to `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for input, just return `null` if it isn't present.

```js
function foo(input){
  // Test for no input (there are several ways to do this)
  if(input === "" || typeof input == "undefined" || input === null){
     return null;
  }
  
  // There was input
  return input;
}

console.log(foo());         // null
console.log(foo(""));       // null
console.log(foo(null));     // null
console.log(foo("Hello"));  // "Hello"
console.log(foo(0));        // 0
```

Comment: you could also do if(arguments.length === 0){return null}

Comment: @SethWhite `arguments` is deprecated.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments

Comment: The article you linked directs us to `Use the simple variable arguments instead`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments Not saying you should alter your answer, but it is an option for the OP.

Comment: @SethWhite Good to know, but doesn't solve this issue: `foo(""`);`